# Outgoing SPAM Protection for vps

Tags: networking, email

We are providing VPS servers (both openvz and kvm) on  Proxmox VE cluster.

Recently, we have attracted a large number of spammers. While we manage to block the openvz ones by monitoring the number of port 25 connections, we do not have any solutions for KVM. 
We've thought about blocking all port 25 connections, but that might cause issues for the majority of our users (legit ones)

One idea is to route all port 25 traffic to a transparent mail proxy like ASSP, but i am not sure that it will work the way we want it.

Do you have any ideas for better solutions of blocking outgoing spam?

Comment: (I downvoted the question because its not appropriate to this site - the question is to vague without knowing your usage case, and its not really a question for enthusiasts - although I sympathise with the problem of spammers).  There is no conceptual reason that you can't monitor the number of connections on port 25 made through a system using KVM - Indeed I would expect the best place to do this would be at a router level which would be agnostic as to the VM technology.  Blocking or transparently proxying port 25 traffic is entirely reasonable provided you advise your customers.

Comment: Might be better answered on server fault, but you could consider and off by default approach that ISPs use and legit users can open a ticket to have it enabled.